# if-else через switch-case в Java

Tags: java, if, switch

Всегда ли конструкцию if-else можно реализовать через аналогичную switch-case в языке Java?
Вопрос был на экзамене в вузе, я предположил, к примеру, что boolean-выражения через switch-case проверить не получится.

Comment: через switch-case насколько я знаю можно проверять только char. int. enum

Comment: можно ли при этом использовать новую переменную? Если да, то можно (установить её в 1, если условие верно, и в 0 -- если не верно), если нет, то не всегда.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Оператор switch работает с [примитивными типами данных](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html): byte, short, char, и int.  Также он работает с перечислимыми (итерируемыми) типами данных.

Можно использовать строки (String) и некоторые специальные производные от примитивных типы данных: Character, Byte, Short, и Integer.

Значение варианта case должно быть константой или литералом. Переменные запрещены.

Также вариант не может быть логического (boolean), вещественного и других типов данных, не перечисленных выше.

Соответственно конструкцию

```
if (x==a){....}
else if (x==b) {...}
else if (x==с) {...}
else if (x==d) {...}
else{...}
}
```

Не получится реализовать.

Получаем, что:

1. не всегда
2. только для итерируемых типов данных

Хотя с [развитием Java](https://habr.com/ru/post/443464/) ситуация может меняться.